# Validation for HTML5 Input Range

Tags: javascript, html, forms, range

How can I add validation for the HTML5 input type range?

It should not be 0. How can I add a warning message, like the default validation messages on other HTML5 input types?

Comment: Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range

Answer (score 1):

Example: `<input type="number" size="6" name="age" min="18" max="99" value="21">`

Some more examples: [HTML5 Validation Types](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

Comment: The example you gave is input type="number". The question is about input type="range".

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the pattern attribute:

```
pattern="[1-1000]"
```

That requires a number entered between 1 and 1000

I'd also add:

```
required="required"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check if the user press the key with an eventlistener via jquery and prevent the use of it

```
$("input").addEventListener("keypress", function (evt) {
        /*your condition*/
        if ( evt.which == /*your keycode*/ )
        {
            evt.preventDefault();
            alert(); /*you error message/code*/
        }
    });
```

http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event_key_codes.aspx